# Rails ActiveRecord querying - array from an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 models, Response and Question. A question has_many responses and thus each response is associated to a question_id.  I want to query the questions corresponding to the responses in the object @responses but I am unsure of the syntax.

```
@reponses = Response.find([1, 10])
@questions = Question.where(:id => [???])
```

My initial thought was something like this, but this syntax is wrong:

```
@reponses = Response.find([1, 10])
@questions = Question.where(:id => @responses.question_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You was very close... Try this

```
@questions = Question.where(:id => @responses.map(&:question_id))
```

but I think you should use the scope in your Response model

Comment: you can also try this is same but more cleaner @questions = Question.where(:id => @responses.pluck(:question_id))

Comment: I am not sure which version of rails @diasks2 is using